# Fungus in a cavern/cellar

Tags: story-identification, b-movies

"B" movie from '50s or '60s: House with a cellar connected to cavern.  There's a fungus that turns people into monsters if they touch it.  Several people have been "eaten" or "absorbed" by the fungus.

Answer (score 2):

"The Unknown Terror" (1957)?

Here is a plot summary from IMDb.

> A woman leads an expedition into a remote jungle to find her long-lost
>   brother, but instead finds a mad scientist who has created a fungus
>   monster that feeds on the local inhabitants.

Here is the complete movie from YouTube.